# Why are dynamically added html table rows and cells not being added to a front end html table?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I'm trying to populate a front-end html table using back-end c#, but none of the HtmlTableRows and HtmlTableCells are showing up in the table. I was able to successfully populate a front-end table dynamically in another asp page in the same project (Images.aspx), but it won't work in this one (Products.aspx).

The front-end tables look like this:

Images.aspx

```
<table id="tblImages" border="1" style="padding:20px;" runat="server"></table>
```

Products.aspx

```
<table id="tblProducts" border="1" style="padding:20px;" runat="server"></table>
```

Here is the C# code from each page:

Page_Load in Images.aspx.cs (working)

```
List<Product> productList = DBL.GetProductList(); // Creates a list of products using a database table

foreach (Product product in productList)
{
    HtmlTableRow tRow = new HtmlTableRow();
    tblImages.Rows.Add(tRow);

    for (int i = 0; i <= 1; i++)
    {
        HtmlTableCell tCell = new HtmlTableCell();
        if (i == 0)
        {
            tCell.InnerText = product.Name;
        }
        else if (i == 1)
        {
            HtmlButton btn = new HtmlButton();
            btn.ID = product.ModelPath;
            btn.Attributes["class"] = "view";
            btn.Attributes["type"] = "button";
            btn.InnerText = "View Model";
            tCell.Controls.Add(btn);
        }
        tRow.Cells.Add(tCell);
    }   
}
```

Page_Load in Products.aspx.cs (not working)

```
List<Product> productList = DBL.GetProductList(); // Creates a list of products using a database table

int column = 1; // keeps track of the column of the cell being populated
const int TOTAL_COLUMNS = 3; // number of columns in the table
HtmlTableRow tRow = new HtmlTableRow();
tblProducts.Rows.Add(tRow);
HtmlTableCell tCell = new HtmlTableCell();
tRow.Cells.Add(tCell);

tCell.Attributes["colspan"] = "3";
tCell.InnerText = "Products";

foreach (Product product in productList) // for every product in the list
{
    if (column == 1) // Create and add a new row if on the first column
    {
        tRow = new HtmlTableRow();
        tblProducts.Rows.Add(tRow);
    }

    // Create cell and populate it

    tCell = new HtmlTableCell();
    tRow.Cells.Add(tCell);
    tCell.InnerHtml += "<h1>" + product.Name + "</h1>" +
                       "<ul><li>$" + product.Cost + "</li>" +
                       "<li>" + product.Description + "</li></ul>";

    if (column == TOTAL_COLUMNS) // if the final column has been reached, reset column counter
    {
        column = 1;
    }
    else // Otherwise, increment column counter
    {
        column++;
    }
}

if (column != 0) // Adds empty cells if the end of the row wasn't reached in the foreach loop
{
    for (int i = column; i < TOTAL_COLUMNS; i++)
    {
        tCell = new HtmlTableCell();
        tRow.Cells.Add(tCell);
    }
}
```

I tried copying the C# code from Images.aspx.cs to Products.aspx.cs to see if it was something with the code in Products, but the table still wouldn't populate.

Comment: Can you add code where you add the table to the Images.aspx code?

Comment: @HansFelixRamos I'm able to, but I'm populating it based on records in a database, so that's why I'm doing it dynamically.